# How to map multiple versions of web service incoming requests to the same Java endpoint method using Spring WS

Tags: spring, spring-ws

We currently use Spring's `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` to map incoming messages to the appropriate Java endpoints. We're going to have a new version of WSDL (with enhanced business functionality) to be made available to the user community while we're also required to continue to support the existing version of WSDL for backward compatibility.

The versioning information will be embedded in the namespaces' URNs, for examples:

urn:mycompany:myproject:mymodule:messages:1.0
urn:mycompany:myproject:mymodule:messages:1.1

Since there's only a small fraction of Java methods that have changed between the old version and the new version, I was wondering what would be the best way to handle those methods that have NOT changed between the two versions in terms of endpoint mapping. In other words, how can I route the incoming messages of both versions to the same Java endpoint method?

One option I was thinking of was to write a custom Spring-ws endpoint mapping class (possibly by extending `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping` class. But before I write any code, I'd like to check with you guys to see:

1) Are there some best practices with respect to supporting multiple versions of WSDLs by a single server side implementation?
2) Does Spring-ws have any out-of-box solutions for this type of the situations?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Spring-WS 2.2, there is a `@PayloadRoots` annotation which allows you to map multiple payloads to one method, like so:

```
@PayloadRoots({
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "Request1", namespace = "http://springframework.org/spring-ws"),
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "Request2", namespace = "http://springframework.org/spring-ws")
    })
public void doIt(@RequestPayload Source payload) {
    ...
}
```

I'd also like to point you to the `PayloadTransformingInterceptor`, which transforms the payload of the SOAP message using XSLT stylesheet. Depending on the differences between the two versions of the WSDL, you could transform the "old" requests to the new format with one XSLT, thus letting them be handled by the "new" endpoint. In turn, the "new" responses can be transformed to the old format again with another XSLT.

Comment: Thanks Arjen for the information, that's exactly what I needed. A couple of follow-up questions: 1) since we're currently running on Spring-WS 2.1, I was wondering if there's release note of some sort that you could point me to that would help me understand the main differences between v2.1 and v2.2. 2) since Java 8 is going to support repeating annotations, I'm curious to know if you think it's likely that Spring-WS will directly support methods annotated with multiple @PayloadRoot annotations in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Spring-WS 2.2 is a minor version bump, so it should be backward compatible  with 2.1. The major new feature in 2.2 is code configuration through the `@EnableWs` annotation. There were also some library upgrades involved. With regard to supporting Java 8 repeating annotations: that is planned, but not there yet.

Comment: Thanks very much Arjen. Appreciate the information.

Comment: Unlike the previous versions where a parent maven project "spring-ws-parent" declares all the common dependencies, in Spring-WS 2.2, the "core", "support" and "security" projects declare their own dependencies, and the dependencies are declared with the "compile" scope. As the result, an application that uses Spring-WS needs to declare the runtime dependencies, e.g. "wsdl4j", by itself. Is this change by design?

Comment: Yes. We switched to Gradle from Maven, and this is a result of that.

Comment: Support for `@Repeatable` annotations will be in Spring-WS 2.2.1. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-877