# Spring-WS : How to process correctly Soap Request with two elements in message Body

Tags: spring-ws

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<D:Envelope xmlns:A="http://xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxxxxx" xmlns:B="http://xxxxxxxxxx.org/xxxx" xmlns:D="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <D:Body id="Body">
        <B:ProcessApplication>
        </B:ProcessApplication>
        <A:AdditionalInfo version="2.0">
        </A:AdditionalInfo>
    </D:Body>
</D:Envelope>
```

This is simplified request which I need to process.
There are two elements B:ProcessApplication and A:AdditionalInfo.

This is my endpoint:

```
@PayloadRoots({
        @PayloadRoot(localPart = "ProcessApplication", namespace = B__NAMESPACE_URI),
        @PayloadRoot(localPart = "AdditionalInfo", namespace = A__NAMESPACE_URI),
})
@ResponsePayload
public MyResponse processRequest(
        @RequestPayload ProcessApplication application,
        @RequestPayload AdditionalInfo addInfo) {

    // .....
    return response;
}
```

With this endpoint I can read ProcessApplication. But I can't read AdditionalInfo.
Is it possible?
How can I modify my endpoint to get the second element?

Another question how can I read whole Body, Envelope, Request?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no possibility to have multiple root elements in the request body. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742646/how-to-add-more-than-one-root-element-into-spring-ws-webservice-envelopes-body) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775773/soap-body-with-two-elements). But still it is not clear to me why it should not generally work, because the [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12/#soapbody) allows multiple message body elements.

It seems to me the implementation frameworks in the reality count with the fact, multiple elements can be always bound together under one root, so the support for multiple root elements is not there - at least it seems to be so in Spring-WS.

You could try, what comes into the input, if you use following method declaration - annotation with the SOAP action (your client the has to fill the soap action attribute correctly):

```
@SoapAction(value = "http://YourNamespace" + "/" + "YourActionName")

@ResponsePayload
public MyResponse processRequest(
        @RequestPayload Source aPayloadSource) {

    // .....
    return response;
}
```

Maybe the `aPayloadSource` parameter could then contain the complete body of the message with both elements, I never tried it, I would be courious if it could work... Then you should do the unmarshalling to the objects by yourself.

Your approach with multiple payload roots with annotation `PayloadRoots` probably does not work, because it seems to be intended to be used for multiple one-root-element-messages handled by the same method.

It is useful for example for the support of multiple versions of the data coming from various clients, like described for example in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656860/how-to-map-multiple-versions-of-web-service-incoming-requests-to-the-same-java-e) - then you probably have to perform the unmarshalling of the passed payload source by yourself similary like in my example with the `@SoapAction` annotation.